# Ruby features vs Java

Tags: java, ruby, rubygems

I am a Java programmer using Ruby for the first time, and I have a few questions about how some features compare between the two languages.

1. Is the notion of a constructor relevant in Ruby? If yes, how does the behavior compare to Java constructors?
2. In Java, we generally keep separate `.java` files for different classes (when not nested). Is there a similar practice in Ruby? Or is each class itself not as important as in Java?
3. How do you extend a class (or `.rb` file)? I would like to extend a class and call `super` inside my local constructor to initialize some items.
4. How do you access the methods of a class in a `.rb` file, from a different class in another `.rb` file?
5. Are Ruby "gems" equivalent to Java packages?

Comment: https://www.ruby-lang.org is a good starting point to answer your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Yes. There is concept of constructor which behaves like *Java one*. However, the constructor method is called `initialize` in Ruby, when in Java, the constructor has the same name as of class itself. eg:

```
 class Foo
   def initialize
     # initialization logic here
   end
 end
```

**2)** Yes, it's rathe considered a best practice to store classes per file - separately, but it is not constrained by language.

**3)** For inheritance, there is different syntax in Ruby. Please consider following code:

```
class Parent
end

class Child < Parent
end
```

**4)** It is actually quite similar to Java, you use `.` to indicate method on object:

```
class Person
  def name
    "Tester"
  end
end

p = Person.new
puts p.name
```

**5)** There is not really concept of packages in Ruby, but you might use `modules` to *namespace* your classes, eg:

```
module Foo1
  class Biz
  end
end

module Foo2
  class Biz
  end
end

b1 = Foo1::Biz.new
b2 = Foo2::Biz.new
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes. No big difference.
2. Yes. More freedom in ruby though. (If you want to you can even define the same class in several files....) Apart from classes there are also modules that can be used as mixin - a sort of multiple inheritance.
3. The `<` operator is used for inheriting another class. It is the `extends` of ruby. In the subclass constructor you can call super just like in Java.
4. Instance methods are accessed just like in Ruby with a dot. Class methods can be accessed as in Java with a dot after the class name. Or with a double colon.
5. No. Ruby has no packages. Often modules are used around classes to provide a namespace in order to avoid clashes. Gems in ruby are more like a jar file (a maven dependency for example) in java.

Answer (score 0):

> Is constructor a relevant thing in Ruby? If yes, any change in behavior compared to Java?

No, there are no constructors in Ruby. Unlike Java, which has three different kinds of "methods" (instance methods, static methods, and constructors), Ruby has exactly one kind of methods: instance methods.

> In Java, we generally keep separate .java files for different classes(if not nested). Is the approach same in Ruby?

No. You would use one file for related concepts. It might be a single class, but then again, it might not. For example, the `set.rb` file in the Ruby standard library contains both the `Set` and the `SortedSet` class.

It might also be that a single class is defined in multiple files. For example, the above-mentioned `set.rb` not only contains the `Set` and `SortedSet` class, it also contains a fragment of the `Array` class which has a `to_set` method for turning an array into a set.

> Or Class itself is not much relevant?

Ruby is a class-based OO language, classes are very much relevant.

> How can i extend one class (or a .rb file)? I would like to extend one class and call the super constructor inside my local constructor to initialize some items.

You can't "extend a file". You can, however extend classes, just like in Java.

> How to access the Methods inside a class (.rb file) from another class (.rb file)?

Again, files have nothing to do with this.

You call methods on objects, just like in pretty much every other OO language, including Java. You don't "access methods inside a class".

> Is packages in Java and Gems in Ruby are the same thing? We used to have multiple packages in a project for tests, utilities etc.Is the approach same in Ruby as well?

No. Gems are more like Maven artefacts. There is no analog to a Java package in Ruby, although one might use modules that way.